# What are these mysterious akka actors like _a _b _xc _y _z

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-monitoring

My akka application is reporting via kamon all the actors in the system.

I am seeing a lot of actors which I do not know where they are coming from, all named `UNDERSCORE LETTER+`, like `_a` `_b` `_c` `_d` `_e` `_f` and `_xc` `_xy` `_hj`

What are these actors and where are they coming from? They are all in the `/user` hierarchy.